# Use bigint and float perl

Tags: perl

I am extremely new to Perl, so I hope you will excuse my inexperience.

I have the following lines of code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX 'ceil';
use bigint;


my($g, $y, $n) = ($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1], $ARGV[2]);

my $z = ceil(sqrt($n-1));

my $entry;

print "list1: \n";
for my $v (0 .. $z) {
    $entry = ($g ** $v) % $n;
    $entry = ($entry ** ($n - 2)) % $n;
    $entry = ($entry * $y) % $n;

    print "$entry : $v\n";
}

print "list2: \n";
for my $u (0 .. $z) {
    $entry = ($g ** ($u * $z)) % $n;
    print "$entry: $u\n";
}
```

I need to use the bigint environment because of some following statements. Whenever I look into `$z` it evaluates to 6 instead of 7, when i call my program with `$n = 41`. It looks as if the bigint environment rounds the value of the `sqrt` method. I also tried to use BigFloat instead of bigint, but then the result of `$entry = ($g ** ($u * $z)) % $n;` gets calculated wrong (with `($g, $y, $n) = (15, 38, 41)` the result is 3, when `$u` reached 3 in the for loop, but should be 26 instead).

Is there any option to avoid this rounding, so I can use float while calculating the square root and bigint in all following statements, so the pow operation works properly?

My call is `perl program.pl 15 38 41`. I try to implement the [baby-step-giant-step algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step).

Comment: You should avoid using the default import set of POSIX as noted in [CAVEATS](https://perldoc.pl/POSIX#CAVEATS); `use POSIX 'ceil';` will get just the function you want.

Comment: Re "*I also tried to use BigFloat instead of bigint, but then the result of `$entry = ($g ** ($u * $z)) % $n;`*", `use bigint;` has no direct effect on that statement. `use bigint;` only has a an effect on numerical literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend [Math::BigFloat](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigFloat.html) and [Math::BigInt](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigInt.html) over the [bigint](https://perldoc.perl.org/bigint.html) pragma, practically always.

The pragma is "*just a thin wrapper around various modules of the Math::BigInt family*" says the (linked) doc, but has very non-trivial actions (the "*Description*" conveys it). Instead, use the classes to set up what you want burdened with infinite precision support, itself non-trivial and costly.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Math::BigFloat;

my($g, $y, $n) = ($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1], $ARGV[2]);

my $z = sqrt($n-1);
say $z; 

my $num = Math::BigFloat->new( $z );
say $num;

my $num_ceil = $num->bceil();
say $num_ceil;
```

---

**Update**    The shown calculation has no need for a big-number exponent

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use POSIX 'ceil';
use Math::BigInt;

my ($g, $y, $n) = @ARGV;

my $z = ceil(sqrt($n-1));

my $bg = Math::BigInt->new($g);

my $e;
for my $u (0 .. $z) {
    $e = $bg->copy->bmodpow($u*$rnd, $n);
    say "$u:  $e";
}
```

There happens to be a [bmodpow](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigInt.html#bmodpow()) method, doing exactly what's needed and being 
"*far superior*" at it.  Most arithmetic methods *modify their operands*, thus `copy()` is chained in to preserve `$bg` for the next iteration.  See "*Modifying and =*" bullet under [Caveats in docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigInt.html#CAVEATS).

I declare `$e` outside of the loop to avoid the (copy) constructor running every time in the loop as the variable becomes (is assigned) a `BigInt` object, returned by the method. (I am not certain that this is needed or that it helps though.)

Comment: I already tried to use BigFloat, but i run into problems when calculating stuff like ```($g ** ($u * $z)) % $n```...

Comment: @HeinzBauer Oh, I see the statement now (but it doesn't spell out the "_problems_").  You can use this alongside any other tool, converting to and fro. Can you explain what kinds of problems you run into? I'd be surprised if the problem were with this module in particular. Best edit the question so you can state the problem (with an example) that can then be dealt with.

Comment: @HeinzBauer I've run your calculations from the question and I don't see the problem.  Can you specify what "problems" you run into?  Can you update your code showing precisely what you get vs. what you expect?

Comment: thanks, i edited the question. The problem i mean is maybe an integer overflow when calculating 15^(3*7) mod 41, which should result in 26 and not in 3, if i am not wrong.

Comment: @HeinzBauer I see, thank you. I get the 26 for `$u==3` ...? (Copy-pasted your second loop.)  Need to run now but I'll amend my post later to add calculations.

Comment: thats funny, i get 3 for ```$u==3``` when ever changing the "use" section to ```use Math::BigFloat``` or ```use Math::BigInt```. What am i missing?

Comment: @HeinzBauer Updated with an added section, with your calculation example

Answer (score 4):

you need to use `bignum`, not `bigint`:

```
$ cat bauer.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX;
use bigint;


my($g, $y, $n) = ($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1], $ARGV[2]);

my $z = ceil(sqrt($n-1));

$ perl r.pl 
1.41421356237309504880168872420969807857
```

With your program signature:

```
$ cat bauer.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX;
use bignum;


my($g, $y, $n) = ($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1], $ARGV[2]);

my $z = ceil(sqrt($n-1));
print STDOUT "$z\n";

$ perl bauer.pl 1 2 48
7
```

Comment: I'll also note that while sqrt is overloaded to maintain BigFloat precision, POSIX::ceil is not. Math::BigFloat has a `bceil` method that avoids the intermediate conversion to a native float, so it would be better to do `my $z = sqrt($n-1)->bceil;` or use the methods entirely such as `my $z = $n->bsub(1)->bsqrt->bceil;`

Comment: It seems that bignum isn't enough for my purposes. Later, i call ```$entry = ($g ** ($u * $z)) % $n;``` with ```$g = 15```, ```$u = 3```, ```$z = 7``` and ```$n = 41```, which evaluates to 3 instead of 26.

Comment: @HeinzBauer Please update your question with the whole code (simplified but complete) that is giving you the wrong result, what you get and what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

> *Whenever I look into $z it evaluates to 6 instead of 7,*

`use bigint;` causes numeric literals to be replaced with Math::BigInt objects. For example,

```
1
```

gets replaced with

```
Math::BigInt->new(1)
```

Math::BigInt in turn overrides a number of operators when a Math::BigInt object is used as an operand.

As such,

```
use bigint;
my $z = ceil(sqrt($n-1));
```

is equivalent to

```
use Math::BigInt;
my $z = ceil(sqrt($n-Math::BigInt->new(1)));
```

which is equivalent to

```
use Math::BigInt;

my $temp = Math::BigInt->new(1);   #  1 [BigInt]
$temp->bneg;                       # -1 [BigInt]
$temp->badd($n);                   # 40 [BigInt]
$temp->bsqrt();                    #  6 [BigInt]      <--- XXX
$temp = $temp->numify;             #  6 [Primitive]
my $z = ceil($temp);               #  6 [Primitive]
```

So, you are using a Math::BigInt when you don't want to. Don't do that!!! Simply use

```
# No "use bigint;"!!!
my $z = ceil(sqrt($n-1));
```

Of course, the algorithm to which you linked actually calls for

```
# No "use bigint;"!!!
my $z = ceil(sqrt($n));
```

---

Because `use bigint;` can have large effects at a distance, I personally find `use bigint;` far too magical. I'd much rather use `Math::BigInt->new(...)` where appropriate rather than having `use bigint;` convert all my numerical constants into Math::BigInt objects. I'd also rather use Math::BigInt's methods instead of overloaded operators. Far less surprises that way (e.g. such as the loss of big number support when using `ceil`).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw( say );

use Config       qw( %Config );
use Math::BigInt qw( );
use POSIX        qw( ceil );

# Each of the arguments is expected to be in [0, 2^32).
# Should use exponentiation by squaring instead of larger number support.
sub pow_m {
   my ($base, $exp, $mod) = @_;
   my $n = Math::BigInt->new($base);
   $n->bpow($exp);
   $n->bmod($mod);
   return $n->numify();
}

# Each of the arguments is expected to be in [0, 2^32).
# Requires a 64-bit integers or $e might overflow.
sub babystep_giantstep {
   my ($g, $h, $mod) = @_;

   my $m = ceil(sqrt($mod));

   my %table;

   my $e = 1;
   for my $i (0..$m-1) {
      $table{$e} = $i;
      $e = ($e * $g) % $mod;
   }

   my $factor = pow_m($g, $mod-$m-1, $mod);

   $e = $h;
   for my $i (0..$m-1) {
      if (exists($table{$e})) {
         return $i*$m + $table{$e};
      }

      $e = ($e * $factor) % $mod;
   }

   return undef;
}

{
   $Config{uvsize} >= 8
      or warn("Results may overflow\n");

   my ($g, $h, $mod) = @ARGV;   
   my $log = babystep_giantstep($g, $h, $mod);
   say $log;

   my $test = Math::BigInt->new($g);
   $test->bpow($log);
   $test->bmod($mod);
   $test = $test->numify;
   say $test == $h ? "ok" : "not ok";
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. The algorithm i try to implement works slightly different from wikipedia's one, so the ```$n-1``` should work correct. I try it out and tell you if it worked.